# Woocommerce Change "Select option" text in variable product page

Tags: woocommerce

On product page 'dropdown) i'd like to modify the SELECT OPTIONS text and i assume this code could to this but nothing change in my page even if i empty cache.
Thanks for your help

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    global $product;    
    $product_type = $product->product_type;  
    switch ( $product_type ) {
case 'variable':
            return __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code --

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);


function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text($args){
 $args['show_option_none'] = __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' ); 
  return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm little late but below code can also be used .

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
        function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {
            global $product;    
            $product_type = $product->product_type;  
            switch ( $product_type ) {
            case 'variable':
                        return __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' );
                    break;
            }
        
            case 'simple':
                        return __( 'Purchase', 'woocommerce' );
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Reference : https://www.raadeen.com/change-select-options-text-woocommerce/